# Slow TTFB at Cloudflare with Heroku server

Tags: heroku, cloudflare, waterfall

I'm hosting my site at Heroku SaaS and something weird is happening with the Waterfall, to be specific the TTFB number.
When accessing the site through the Heroku dns, I get a excellent TTFB, ~200ms. But, accessing using the Cloudflare DNS, the TTFB is ~750ms, almost 4x the Heroku DNS.
My actual configuration, is just a redirect CNAME to heroku app (app.herokuapp.com) throughing the Cloudfare servers and a page rule to uses the Cloudflare SSL.
Ok, the problem can be at the heroku, or at the redirect CNAME. But is there a way to improve it or do some test to identify the real problem?

[image: cloudflare configuration]

Comment: When you bypass CloudFlare, are you still connecting with SSL? Can you post the URLs to be compared?

Comment: @Jules yes. The URLS are, Cloudflare (hidronat.traus.com.br) & heroku (hidronat.traus.com.br.herokudns.com). hidroant.traus.com.br has the cloudflare certificate

Comment: Have you solved this?' I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: yes, migrate to another server :( I didn't find any solution. Sorry!